# Angular "Auto-Deploy" in firebase hosting

Tags: angular, firebase

I have a angular web project integrated with firebase (firestore/Auth/Hosting). I have 20+ different customers each one need their own implementation/deployment in your firebase account.

[mary.web.app](https://mary.web.app) |
[john.web.app](https://john.web.app) |
[etc.web.app](https://etc.web.app) |
...

I'd like to know if is possible to publish/to pack my web project in some place and my customers can click and deploy it themself like a google store app?

They will need to update the firebase project information:

```
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx",
  projectId: "xxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx",
  appId: "y:xxx",
  measurementId: "xxx",
```

My idea is not need deploy 20+ times to each fix/update.

- Angular CLI: 15.2.4
- Node: 18.10.0
- Angular: 15.2.0
- Typescript 4.9.5

Thank you in advance

Comment: So, you have multiple Firebase applications built from the same source, which you currently deploy by hand using Firebase hosting (CLI?). And now your goal is that customers are able to deploy new version by themselves. Or do you want to automatically deploy them all at once by yourself? Either way, firebase offers a REST API for deployment which you could use https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/api-deploy?hl=de

Comment: @Eddi Exacly, I want to automatize deploy to each costumer deploy themself. Because they will need update the firebase configs data. apiKey: "xxx", etc...

Comment: Just ask them for the information. It isn't a secret. Since it is included in the source it is publicly available.

Comment: @Robin Dijkhof my idea is not need to ask for information to 10k costumers or more.

Comment: This could heavily depend on how they deploy your app initially, do they have access to the repository and just pull from it? Do they fork your repo? Do they download the releases and then replace the project info? I ask because I can see how a github fork could use github actions to automate the deployment process on each release.

Comment: @Johalternate They haven't access to code. But can have access to docker hub or if possible, access a "git action button" in some page or something else.